# Non static method in scala Enum

Tags: java, scala, enums

In a Java Enum it is possible to add a non static method that works based on that enums instance.

So given the following enum this code `TestEnum.FOO.getName();` would print "foo"

```
public static enum TestEnum {
    FOO("foo"),
    BAR("bar");
    private final String name;

    private TestEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to do this in scala?

Comment: In your comment to Markus answer you mention a *Library* which expects an *enum*. Do you mean like `<T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface>`? Then I think, you cannot create anything in scala that will fit in there.

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried many different approaches now. I now made a more general Java enum. I was just hoping to find a solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You can define abstract members inside the trait and then implement them in the concrete cases:

```
sealed trait TestEnum { val name: String }
case object Foo extends TestEnum { val name = "foo" }
case object Bar extends TestEnum { val name = "foo" }
```

demonstration in REPL:

```
scala> val (foo,bar): (TestEnum,TestEnum) = (Foo,Bar)
foo: TestEnum = Foo
bar: TestEnum = Bar
scala> foo.name
res1: String = "foo"
scala> bar.name
res2: String = "bar"
```

Edit: You can define getName in the `TestEnum` accessing the `name` like this:

```
sealed trait TestEnum { val name: String; def getName = name }
case object Foo extends TestEnum { val name = "foo" }
case object Bar extends TestEnum { val name = "bar" }
```

Or you can also just forget about the `val` and use:

```
sealed trait TestEnum { def getName }
case object Foo extends TestEnum { def getName = "foo" }
case object Bar extends TestEnum { def getName = "bar" }
```

Comment: That is great but the Library I'm using expects me to use an enum that implements an Interface containing the `getName()` method.

Comment: well you can name the `val` `getName` or define `getName` in the trait as well

Comment: Better, make your sealed trait extend this interface your library expects.